# How to Get Value from Json Array mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, json

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"customer_name":"John Doe","email":"johndoe@email.com","cart":"[{" product_id":17," description":" Tshirt"," price":50}]", } |

I have data above

when i used this query, it always return as null

```
select value->>"$.cart[*].product_id" from orders
```

and

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(value, '$.cart[*].product_id') from orders
```

how to write the proper query to get product_id from cart array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you posted is not valid JSON. I've marked the problems with 1,2,3 below.

```
{...,"cart":"[{" product_id":17," description":" Tshirt"," price":50}]", }
            1                                                         23
```

For 1 and 2, you shouldn't put the array in double-quotes. Double-quotes are for strings. It would be okay if you *intended* `cart` to be a string with content that happens to resemble a JSON array, but there are double-quote characters inside that string, so it makes the syntax confused.

For 3, you must not have a trailing `,` in JSON without another field or element following it.

The fixed JSON looks like this:

```
{"customer_name":"John Doe","email":"johndoe@email.com","cart":[{" product_id":17," description":" Tshirt"," price":50}] }
```

If you fix those problem, the next problem is that you have spaces in some field names. You should be able to do this:

```
select value->>'$.cart[*].product_id' ...
```

But you can't, because the field name isn't `"product_id"`, it's `" product_id"` (with a leading space).

JSON does allow field names to contain spaces. But if you use field names with spaces, you must query it like this:

```
select value->>'$.cart[*]." product_id"' ...
```

But I would recommend you fix the spaces to make it easier to query. Like this:

```
{"customer_name":"John Doe","email":"johndoe@email.com","cart":[{"product_id":17,"description":"Tshirt","price":50}] }
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, actually there are backslash (\" product_id\") on cart when i wrote the question, but not show when i posted the question,
i need to remove "\" and remove " outside cart array.